# Discord Translation Bot AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, discord, bots, google-translation-api

So I am trying to code a discord bot in python and it has been going pretty well it translates most messages across 2 different channels fairly well but on some messages I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

My code is:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

dutch_channel = 123456789
english_channel = 123456789

translator = googletrans.Translator()
text = message.content

if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.channel.id == dutch_channel:
    
    try:

        text_translated = translator.translate(text, dest = 'english')

        channel = client.get_channel(english_channel)
        await channel.send(f'__**{message.author.name}**__ \r\n {text_translated.text}')
    except AttributeError: 

        print(message.content)

if message.channel.id == english_channel:

    try:

        text_translated = translator.translate(text, dest = 'dutch')

        channel = client.get_channel(dutch_channel) 
        await channel.send(f'__**{message.author.name}**__ \r\n {text_translated.text}')
    except AttributeError:

        print(message.content)

await client.process_commands(message)
```

I think it's breaking because of special characters, the least I know is that special characters always cause the issue.

Additional information:

full stacktrace:

```
message
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wessel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Wessel\Desktop\PythonBot\bot.py", line 88, in on_message
    output = f' \r\n {text_translated.text}'
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text_translated' referenced before assignment
```

Discord.py version 1.5.1
GoogleTrans version 3.0.0

Comment: 1. Post full error traceback. 2. Show how you are importing googletrans, initializing it and which version you have installed.

Comment: I added the full stacktrace and the discord.py version, I don't know how to show you that I'm initializing google trans because this is almost all the code in the entire program

Comment: The googletrans version is relevant.

Comment: Added GoogleTrans version 3.0.0 for py 3.9

Comment: Can't see the error. You will have to catch the exact message the error occurs in. Also make sure your `message.content` is not empty (can happen if someone just posts a picture)

Comment: It does indeed also trigger when the message is empty though I can't give you the exact message as it can trigger on any message and I haven't been able to discern what's causing it exactly yet

Comment: Your code is failing here: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/blob/master/googletrans/gtoken.py#L62
It expects to find something. But the RegEx is fine as long as the string it is checking against is not empty, see: https://regex101.com/r/CX0jIe/1/

You can wrap only the `translator.translate(text, dest = 'english')` in a `try except` catching the `AttributeError` error. And when you enter the except block you just print to console `message.content`. You do have to make it skip the scenarios where `message.content` is empty.

Comment: Okay I am now getting a new error saying:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text_translated' referenced before assignment 
On messages I assume it doesn't know a translation for

Comment: In future post your updated code. That error is probably the variable doesn't exist. If you don't manage to translate anything you shouldn't try to attempt to access that variable`s `text` attribute. Anyway I gotta go now.

Comment: Ah I will update the code but thanks for all the help until now :D

Comment: Your `text_translated` is defined in `try block` and you're using it in `except block`, just remove that `{text_translated.text}` and it should be ok.

Comment: Okay so as you suggested I put everything in the try block and it works like a charm and prints out all the messages that didn't get translated though I would like to know if there is a way to still translate these messages or is that not possible and do I just have to accept that they won't be translated because most of them should be easily translateable

Comment: Hi, GoogleTrans is not an official library and is using the web API of translate.google.com to get results. However, the recommended endopint is translation.googleapis.com and I would strongly encourage to use [Google's official client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup) to get more stable results.